# How to add custom style to React Datepicker (HackerOne)?

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, styling

[image]

I want to make this DateTime picker take up the entire screen and also change the style of some parts such as the size of each time slot and day.

I've got this from https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-default and the github repo for it is https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check in the examples the [Custom calendar class name](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-calendar-class-name).

[image: Custom calendar class name]

It defines a custom class name with the `DatePicker` property `calendarClassName="rasta-stripes"`. The class-name `rasta-stripes` is defined as follow:

```css
.rasta-stripes {
  .react-datepicker__week:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    background-color: #215005;
  }
  .react-datepicker__week:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    background-color: #eea429;
  }
  .react-datepicker__week:nth-child(3n + 3) {
    background-color: #a82a15;
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, to style some parts just make a reference to the classes React DatePicker uses for itself to override it. You can check which classes exist by inspecting the sources with the browser of your preference.

To make it full screen for example just override the `react-datepicker-popper` class-name by removing `transform` and adding `left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;` and then change every fixed size child to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is to override the built-in [react-datepicker css classes](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/main/src/stylesheets/datepicker.scss).

1. In dev tools, locate the class you want to edit (eg. `react-datepicker__day`)
2. In your global css file, add an entry for that class
3. Update the style

```css
.react-datepicker__day {
  background: #0000FF;
}
```

[image]

Some properties are harder to override. For these, you need to include the `!important` modifier after the value:

```css
.react-datepicker__day {
  color: red !important;
}
```

If you don't want to directly override these built-in classes, you can also define custom class names and add them to your global css file like before:

```js
<DatePicker
              inline
              selected={selectedLocalDateTime}
              onChange={onDateChange}
              dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
              className='test-class'
              wrapperClassName='wrapper-class'
              calendarClassName='calendar-class'
            />
```